# Why does my screensaver say [myname]'s Macbook Pro (4)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screensaver

So I have a macbook pro running 10.10.3.

I am still using the default screensaver, which (when the computer was new) said `[MyName]'s Macbook Pro` followed by an image of the apple logo.

After a few weeks of owning the computer, the screensaver just changed, seemingly on it's own, to say `[MyName]'s Macbook Pro (2)`.

Since then, as time has been passing, the number in those parenthesis have been incrementing, and today I am up to `[MyName]'s Macbook Pro (4)`.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Can you open up Terminal and try `hostname`? What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a glitch I've experienced caused by your mac reconnecting to your local network and thinking another computer of the same name is already connected. I'm not sure why it does that, but your computer adds a number to change it's name and avoid what it thinks is two computers with the same name on the network. You can reset the name by going to System Preferences-> Sharing, and editing your computer's name.

Resetting my router solved this problem for me- it's usually done by putting a paper clip inside a hole on the back of the router

Answer (score 1):

If you go into System Preferences > Sharing and change the computer name to something other than the default, I would guess that name would be used by the screensaver, instead of your current string, and not keep getting re-assigned.